# date object doesn't seem to be accurate when compared to today's date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function that takes todays date and compares it to two weeks out. when it's less than or equal to the current date, it's supposed to add a class. However if it's today's date, it's not working. Otherwise it's working fine. Any ideas? Thanks

```
publicMethods.campaignEndDateAlert = function (dateString) {
  if (!dateString) {
    return dateString
  };

  var currentDate = new Date ();
  var twoWeeks = new Date ();
  twoWeeks.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 14);
  var inputDate = new Date(dateString);

  // This is the part that doesn't seem to work - the first part of this if statement
  if ((inputDate >= currentDate) && (inputDate <= twoWeeks)) {  
    dateString = '<span class="red">' + ax.Utils.RFCFormat(dateString, { excludeTime: true }) + '</span>';
  } else { 
    dateString = ax.Utils.RFCFormat(dateString, { excludeTime: true }) 
  };
  return dateString;
};
```

Comment: Is inputDate producing a valid date object? Can you give an example of dateString?

Comment: hi nathan, it is.

Comment: Just noticed the "if it's today's date" portion

Comment: What does your input string look like? Is it precise or just a date? If it's just a day/month/year this won't work because `new Date()` produces a precise date/time (i.e 2017-07-13T15:12:03.362Z) but with an imprecise date string will make the time something like 8:00:00

Comment: Your code seems to work fine in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/4js872kt/. The important part we need to see in order to help you is the value of `dateString`

Comment: Thank you all, I believe Nathan's answer worked! Let me test and see

Comment: thanks @RoryMcCrossan for the fiddle - I think we're set here. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the information you provided:

You said that if it is today's date it doesn't work as expected. That is because `new Date()` will provide a date object with today's date *and* time. *IF* the value of dateString is something like `"07-13-2017"` *without* the time, you will need to strip the time out of the `currentDate` object if you expect `inputDate >= currentDate` to be true. Try using `currentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);` before comparing to inputDate.

Comment: Yes Nathan, thank you. I compared the date objects and one of them had the time included so this solution works. Appreciate it !!